# virtualbox 4.3 installation using ansible

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, wget, ansible

I am trying to get `virtualbox4.3` installed on `ubuntu 12.04` using an Ansible playbook. However I am running into some problems setting the key

My playbook looks like

```
---
- name: add dependency manager
  apt: name=dkms
  sudo: yes

- name: add virtualbox repo for precise
  apt_repository: repo='deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian precise contrib'
  sudo: yes

- name: add key
  action: command wget -q http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | apt-key add -
  sudo: yes
```

The script complains

> failed: [localhost] => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["wget", "-q",
>   "http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox.asc",
>   "-O-", "|", "apt-key", "add", "-"], "delta": "0:00:00.709146", "end":
>   "2014-02-28 10:23:29.718311", "item": "", "rc": 4, "start":
>   "2014-02-28 10:23:29.009165"} stdout: -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY
>   BLOCK----- Version: GnuPG v1.4.9 (GNU/Linux)
>   mQGiBEv ... etc

Any suggestions? I guess I am making a mistake with the add key part, but it is not clear to me what is wrong. I have based my script on the following apt instruction http://www.howopensource.com/2013/04/install-virtualbox-ubuntu-ppa/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `action: command` block, consider using Ansible's native `apt_key:` module as documented in http://docs.ansible.com/apt_key_module.html.

In your specific case it would be:

```
- name: add VirtualBox repo signing key
  apt_key: state=present
           url=http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox.asc
```